# How to style texts attributes in android graphical layout

Tags: android, attributes, textview

I am designing a view where I have textviews. Now I want to change the attributes of the text in the textview like making it bold, changing text color and fontsize etc. How can I do it in the graphical design mode instead of xml mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to learn the xml tags for layout design..
Graphical design works only in few cases(I tried it, trust me). Also remember to take a look at the layout in the device every time you make a change, it might look differently from what you get from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to set text attributes programmatically? You can use methods in the [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the text view you want to change, select properties, then select your text attributes from there.

Comment: i saw in the properties the "Text Color". but when i choose it, it asks for color resources. How to get the color resources? Isn't there anything simple like to change text color, a color dialog box will appear and we will just choose the color by clicking on desired color?